# Error in rep(xi, length.out = nvar) : attempt to replicate an object of type 'S4'

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr, sparklyr

I'm Unable to a rbind on two dataframes.

I created one using the other dataframe, like this,data1 is my original dataframe. With same column names and order

```
s1 <- data.frame(A =rep(first(data1)[[1]],9),
              B=rep(first(data1)[[2]],9),
              C = rep(first(data1)[[3]],9),
              D = rep(first(data1)[[4]],9),
              E = rep(first(data1)[[5]],9),
              F = rep(first(data1)[[6]],9),
              G = rep(first(data1)[[7]],9),
              H = rep(first(data1)[[8]],9),
              I = forecast_month_ext(first(data1)[[8]]),
              K=rep(0,9))
```

The above code gave me a dataframe i wanted.
I'm not able to bind this and the original one. It's throwing an error.

Error in rep(xi, length.out = nvar) :    attempt to replicate an object of type 'S4'
I took top 9 rows of the dataframe and tried rbind. It threw same error.
Rbind code

```
datax<-rbind(data,s1)
```

I even tried this with no success.

```
data<-rbind(data,s1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s1 <- createDataFrame(data.frame(A =rep(first(data1)[[1]],9),
          B=rep(first(data1)[[2]],9),
          C = rep(first(data1)[[3]],9),
          D = rep(first(data1)[[4]],9),
          E = rep(first(data1)[[5]],9),
          F = rep(first(data1)[[6]],9),
          G = rep(first(data1)[[7]],9),
          H = rep(first(data1)[[8]],9),
          I = forecast_month_ext(first(data1)[[8]]),
          K=rep(0,9)))
```

**createDataFrame()** - I missed this.

Adding this as it can help anyone coming in search